# Storing dates and datetimes using the unix epoch

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, sqlite, unix-timestamp

I need a universal way to store dates and datetimes in several databases (for now Sqlite, MySql and PostgreSql).
I need datetimes to have microseconds precision.

- Sqlite does not have date and datimes built in.
- MySql datetime does not have microseconds precision.

So i thought to keep dates as integers (4 bytes) - days since the unix epoch, and datetimes as integers (8 bytes) - microseconds since the unix epoch.

Questions:

1. What's the right way to convert a date to days since unix epoch? I found this: `time.time()/86400` (python).
2. Is it robust to keep datetimes as timestamps? What about the leap seconds - will this influence the accuracy? What if at some point in time a future date was stored as timestamp but later a leap second appeared?
3. Any other issues?

Comment: [MariaDB version 5.3](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/microseconds-in-mariadb) will have microseconds in time, datetime and timestamp types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. time() / 86400 is fine. I've done this before; you should not anticipate any problems. You could also store time() truncated down to the nearest multiple of 86400, which might be a little nicer because you can pass it to various functions that already accept a `time_t` and have it come out as midnight UTC on the date in question.
2. Don't worry about leap seconds. Only specialized software takes them into account. The system date&time on all general purpose operating systems, and all general purpose date&time libraries pretend they don't exist. Your NTP server implements them by just fudging the system clock ahead by one second whenever they happen.
3. C's `gettimeofday` returns the time as two separate 4-byte integer values: seconds since the epoch, and microseconds since the start of the second (`struct timeval`). Similarily, C's `clock_gettime` returns the time as two separate 4-byte integer values: seconds since the epoch, and nanoseconds since the start of the second (`struct timespec`). If you care about compatibility with existing representations of time, you might choose one of those two formats instead of an 8-byte integer counting microseconds since the epoch. On the other hand both of those have the y2.038k bug (unless the first integer is extended to 8 bytes, for a total of 12 bytes) and they are less convenient to use in a database. So I think your idea of microseconds since the epoch is just fine.